# jQuery img src replace conflict with jQuery/jQueryUI libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm encountering the following problem.

In Drupal I have the following includes for jQuery libraries in html.tpl.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='/tappr-website/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js'>\x3C/script>")
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

and various jQuery effects (magnification, fadein, etc...), in particular what gives me troubles is the following function that is supposed to change dynamically the src of an image when the mouse is over another set of images:

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function(){
        var oldSrc=jQuery("#imageholder").attr("src");

        jQuery("#sell-analytics img").hover(function() {

              //jQuery("#imageholder").attr("src", "image2.png");

                var newSrc = jQuery("#imageholder").attr('src').replace( oldSrc, "image1.png" );
                jQuery("#imageholder").attr("src", newSrc);

            }, function() {

              jQuery("#imageholder").attr("src", oldSrc);

        });


        jQuery("#sell-employee img").hover(function() {

              jQuery("#imageholder").attr("src", "image2.png");

            }, function() {

              jQuery("#imageholder").attr("src", oldSrc);

        });



        jQuery("#sell-sales img").hover(function() {

              jQuery("#imageholder").prop("src", "image3.png");

            }, function() {

              jQuery("#imageholder").prop("src", oldSrc);

        });



        jQuery("#sell-inventory img").hover(function() {

              jQuery("#imageholder").attr("src", "image4.png");

            }, function() {

              jQuery("#imageholder").attr("src", oldSrc);

        });



        jQuery("#sell-webshop img").hover(function() {

              jQuery("#imageholder").attr("src", "image5.png");

            }, function() {

              jQuery("#imageholder").attr("src", oldSrc);

        });         
    });
```

Now, when I don't include the `jquery-1.9.1.js` the function works but all the other animations don't, so when I include all of them everything works except this function.

Had anyone encountered a similar problem?
Should I change the function or the libraries included?

**Note:** there is different methods for every image because I  tried different solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frek! Why are you including 3 jquery files? Here's the latest jquery version from Google CDN. Use this only as:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know why are you including jqueryUI but if its necessary, let it be. And use the following script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Now you can use $ instead of jQuery everytime.

});
```

Comment: I took over this code so I don't (yet at least) why they included all of these jquery libraries